# Implementing jquery in Uiapp

Tags: google-apps-script

I have used the following auto-complete using the jquery and HTML in the google sites as like available in the following code.

For code : [click here](https://raw.github.com/choc2020/jquery/master/autoComplete.html)

This above code is working fine using HTML services.

But I dont know how to invoke this jquery in Uiapp

But I need to apply this auto complete option in the Uiapp, I thought to use of this jquery as a GAS library.

But I have no idea of converting the jquery as GAS library. Please someone guide me to implement this with the help of GAS library and If anybody have idea about using this kind of features in the Uiapp please guide me.

Please help me to achive this autocomplete concept in Uiapp with the help of GAS library.

Tnx in advance,
chocka.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer: **No jQuery with UiApp**. Stick with HTMLService.

BTW: Use the JQuery libraries located on Google server - it's working faster ;-)

Comment: Thanks for your valuable time. I know that there is no straight way to achieve it. But I'm looking for some workaround to achieve this concept in the Uiapp. Is there any Idea to convert this script tag code into GAS library?. Please advise on it. Tnx, CL.